# SQL Two Tables with One Unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables tbl_backupchecks and tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak.

Both tables have two column names, Company and ServerName.

I'd like to return a result set comprising of Company and Servername but in a merged list. Essentially if there is a servername and companyname in tbl_backupchecks_SQLBak that is not in  tbl_backupchecks I want to report on it as well.

In basic terms I want a resultset of rows that is two column; company and servername. I tried writing a left join but it bought back two columns called ServerName. Can this be done?

Comment: If a row exists in Both tables, should it appear in your results once or twice?

Comment: Can you assume one contains the other?

Comment: I think this page describes the problem and a solution well: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your columns `Company` and `Servername` are datatypes that can be DISTINCT, you could use a UNION query:

```
SELECT Company, Servername FROM tbl_backupchecks
UNION
SELECT Company, Servername FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a union should do that for you

```
   SELECT Company, ServerName
   FROM tbl_backupchecks
   UNION
   SELECT Company, ServerName
   FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT  Company, ServerName 
  FROM  tbl_backupchecks 
UNION
SELECT  Company, ServerName 
  FROM  tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a UNION:

For distinct rows between both tables use this:

```
SELECT Company,ServerName
FROM tbl_backupchecks
UNION
SELECT Company,ServerName
FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

For all rows from both tables (will not remove duplicate rows that exist in both tables) use this:

```
SELECT Company,ServerName
FROM tbl_backupchecks
UNION ALL
SELECT Company,ServerName
FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks

UNION

SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
```

(Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` if you want to keep the duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want unique records from both, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company, ServerName
FROM
(
SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks
UNION
SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks_sqlbak
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a union of the 2 tables.  Something like:

```
SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks
UNION 
SELECT Company, ServerName FROM tbl_backupchecks_SQLBak
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that also tell you where the record is

```
select Company, ServerName, sum(case when is_bak=0 then 0 else 1) as in_bak, sum(case when is_bak=0 then 1 else 0) as in_not_bak from (
select Company, ServerName,0 as is_bak from tbl_backupchecks union 
select  SELECT Company, ServerName, 1 as is_bak FROM tbl_backupchecks_SQLBak
) group by Company, ServerName
```